# Proper way of including css and div in php

Tags: php, html

I have a simple php page, and im trying to include style in to my side bar menu usinf a div and then include the css file at the top. could someone please let me know where i have gone wrong as im very new to php.

**Code**

```
<?php
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="script/style.css" type="text/css">';
include 'library/connect.php';

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Bands` ORDER BY  `Venue` DESC");

echo "
    <h1>Band Name</h1>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    ?>
    <div class="menu_div">
        <li>
            <a href="list_item.php?id=<?php echo $row['Band_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></a>
        </li>
    </div>
<?php
}

echo "</table>";
    include 'library/close.php';
?>
```

so my code works except the css ... but im not sure i have it as efficient as it could be

Comment: place it like normal html above the opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: hmm, thats what ive done but its not working.

Comment: is the link tag for the css pointing to the correctly named file and/or located within the `head` tag?

Comment: just going through that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**..IF you have the correct path to your css file...** you should be able to place traditional `HTML` on the same page similar to how you would set up a normal page, and then place the `<?php` within that page.

Example CODE:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="script/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<?php

include 'library/connect.php';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Bands` ORDER BY  `Venue` DESC");

echo "<h1>Band Name</h1>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<div class="menu_div">
    <li>
        <a href="list_item.php?id=<?php echo $row['Band_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></a>
        </li>
    </div>
<?php
}

echo "</table>";
include 'library/close.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Phlume said, if the path is correct and you have properly referenced the class "menu_div" in the stylesheet, you can simply include the link in the head.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="script/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    YOUR PHP CODE
?>
</body>
</html>
```

You might want to check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp for help understanding how php and html interact.